# How to install core GMS packages to use Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, huawei, google-play-services, emui

I am having an issue with my brand new phone Huawei Mate 9 EMUI 5.0 from China. Somehow, when I want to install WhatsApp on it, I get the following message

> Install core GMS packages to use Google Play Store

Here is the screenshot

[image]

What can I do to solve this? I just got the phone and I am lost.

Comment: Your device probably iis meant for Chinese market and they need to install an app to have Google services as [mentioned in this XDA](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/mate-9/how-to/gms-core-t3510121/amp/) post. You can try by downloading that app of emui version matches

Comment: Hello @beeshyams i landed on that before but they say `then update your firmware to B135` but my current version is MHA-AL00C00B186

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that - recall similar issue being discussed in Huawei forums couple of years ago when i owned a Huawei device. Their updates,  rollouts, lack of transparency,  customer service etc stink, IMO (Sorry for the rant ) but you would need to delve into their forums or wait for  regulars from China  to answer this @Andy Yan

Comment: This may be helpful [Open Source implementation of Google Play Services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2184/29904)

Comment: Xavier is right (I just wanted to recommend the same). microG reportedly is sufficient to have Playstore running (though you can also use e.g. Yalp instead, which is another front-end for Playstore), and AFAIR also for other GApps. I'm using microG here as I wanted to get rid of those sniffing GApps – but for that very same reason I obviously don't have those GApps running. And especially no WA or the like ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can well remember that Huawei devices can be added with GMS by flashing a flashable GMS package.

You'll need to first find a compatible 3rd party recovery for your phone. IIRC TWRP is (unofficially) available for Mate 9, so you can take a look at XDA Developers Forum.

After flashing recovery, go to [OpenGApps](https://opengapps.org) and download a package that's suitable for your device (arm64-7.1-pico) and flash it via recovery. Voila! You now have GMS and Play Store on your device!