# How do you install Google Play on Huawei Enjoy 7?

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, twrp, huawei

Recently I purchased a Huawei Enjoy 7 from China and brought it back to Canada. (This phone is available only for purchase in China but it works perfectly fine in Canada and the states)

Basically it isn't that easy to get Google Play / Other Google Apps (beacause the phone was meant for China)

I have tried just getting the Google Play Store, as well as Google Play Services from a APK downloader online, but it just shows "Install Core GMS Packages to use google play" This is my main problem.

Huawei phones like the Mate series or the P series (meant for America) can just download an APK for the [GMS Installer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B64ADSfC5LHbMHdlZ2ZONVhXVWM). But on the Huawei Enjoy 7, it doesn't work. (same message when opening google play)

Here's where I find that it gets tricky, according to [this forum post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177312/how-to-install-core-gms-packages-to-use-google-play-store) and this other [stack exchange post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177312/how-to-install-core-gms-packages-to-use-google-play-store), you need to use TWRP to install GMS. (the stack exchange one isn't exactly relevant to my situation because it is a Mate 9)

To anyone experienced with computers/android using TWRP or something that has full access to your phone can have damaging consequences if done wrong. The forum post has a small guide that can somewhat help but it isn't very clear. This other stack exchange post also shows how to use TWRP (there are also links to official guides) but it isn't exactly the same as what the forum post suggests me to do.

My phone is currently running 7.0 nougat and not rooted (EMUI 5.0 I think). And I have the correct "Open GApps project" file on my computer and my phone.

What I want is a **very clear and detailed guide that has official information to back it up** to show my how to properly install Google Play on a Huawei Enjoy 7 using TWRP. Or if there are any other methods on how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods here. If **Method 1** fails or you don't want to go through with it, try **Method 2**.

### Method 1:

I'm going to try something here. It may or may not work. I don't have any phone without play services to test this on.

1. First, download Google installer from Google drive link: [Google installer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0l2sjcF9VU2WkFyWjQxT21pSUU/view?usp=drivesdk)
2. To install the file you will have to go to Setting >> Security >> Allow Unknown Sources. Once you check this option you will be able to install the files.
3. Tap the downloaded APK to initiate the installation process.
4. After completion, launch Google Installer by tapping open or from the home screen. It will have a Chinese name.
5. In the app, tap the big blue button at the bottom to start the install process.
6. It will then  prompt you to install the necessary  packages one after the other

### Method 2:

There is a thread in the XDA forums for your exact problem with the Huawei Enjoy The steps you need to follow are linked [here.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=74481630&postcount=9)
**This method requires you to unlock your bootloader, flash a custom recovery** and install the OpenGapps package of your choice. For your convenience, I am copying all the steps here, but I would suggest you follow the instructions from their source.
**(Bonus note: with help from Google Translate, you can get some more clarifications [here](http://www.huaweirom.com/guide/5205.html))**

1. Download a Chinese version of TWRP from [here.](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1o89gkKM) You don't need an account, just press the download button
2. Unlock your bootloader. Google will help. You need to get unlock code from Huawei. Go [here](http://www.emui.com/plugin.php?id=unlock&mod=detail), apply and follow the instructions. **All data will get wiped. Backup important data.** Once done you will get a screen with "Phone Unlocked!" written in the bottom
3. Then in the twrp folder you had downloaded you will find a batch file named something like "recovery-twrp一键刷入工具.bat". Run the batch file. The text in the console will be in Chinese but in Windows 10 you can copy and paste the contents of the console into Google Translate. Follow the directions and press 2 when prompted to boot into the recovery.
4. Download from www.opengapps.org and copy the compatible OpenGapps package of your choice (I suggest the micro) into your phone beforehand and then boot into TWRP, choose install, select the package you had copied earlier and then swipe to install. Once done, reboot.

I have not actually tried any of this, but if you get stuck somewhere, please share the screenshots and I'll try to help the best I can.

Comment: I tried "method 1" it doesn't work. Although that is what I expected (see my question paragraph 3-5) I just wanted to let you know that it doesn't work.

Comment: About method 1, i was hoping a different installer would work, but sadly, no.

Comment: Currently. Huawei has stopped handing out unlock codes. Is there any way to get around this? I have a friend that has the same problem as me.

Comment: Currently I'm completely out of the loop for the Huawei side of things. From what I've heard, there is no work around yet, but you can wait and see if some motivated developers find a way. It may take some time, though. Developers are pretty angry at Huawei for their high handedness

Comment: This is link of a website which CLAIMS to be able to unlock bootloader through a paid software. I have not verified this AT ALL. You may give it a look. It does seem shady. https://www.getdroidtips.com/unlock-bootloader-huawei-smartphone/

Comment: Didn't work for me, I will return the device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special GMS installer for Huawei Enjoy 7. Here's the [link](https://mega.nz/#!PWpSmKIR!qurFjrEnjC9aqRoOmz8i3e96hyhQ04QKqLQh1A-lXKA).

I was getting the same issue, but when I used this GMS installer it worked just fine. You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Gy7qgyrxfY). Unfortunately, it's not in English, but still, it is clear.

Comment: Can you add the steps described on the video to your answer in case the video is removed by the author.